# Magento 2 - Enabling Flat Catalog causes SQL error. Reading from "report" tables

Tags: database, error, catalog, magento-2.2.5, flat-catalog

When I enable the flat catalog in my Magento 2.2.5 installation, I get an error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `e`.`list_price`, `e`.`supplier_code`, `e`.`apparel_size`, `e`.`apparel_size_value`, `e`.`apparel_occasion`, `e`.`apparel_occasion_value`, `e`.`apparel_style`, `e`.`apparel_style_value`, `e`.`apparel_gender`, `e`.`apparel_gender_value`, `e`.`material`, `e`.`material_value`, `e`.`exh_size`, `e`.`exh_size_value`, `e`.`exh_adapter`, `e`.`exh_adapter_value`, `e`.`karmak_pn`, `e`.`freight_free`, `e`.`free_shipping`, `e`.`backorder_shipping_message`, `e`.`brands`, `e`.`brands_value`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2'
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) AND (logged_at >= '2018-08-13') AND (logged_at <= '2019-01-20') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (COUNT(report_table_views.event_id) > 0) ORDER BY `views` DESC
 LIMIT 12
```

It looks like Magento is trying to read from `report_event` table and other "report" tables which seems odd for catalog data.

Any ideas on why this error is happening? Do I need certain settings turned on for each attribute? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**Edit:** I have tried `php/bin magento indexer:reindex` with no luck. I have also tried removing all extensions from the app/code/ directory and running the `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `indexer:reindex`, & `cache:flush`. No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

run command index for that, it will solve your case.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: I have tried that multiple times. Even running a setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, indexer:reindex, cache:flush. No luck.

Comment: forgot to tag you @theLight